# Android Studio: Cannot get DialogFragment's inflated layout to match_parent

Tags: android-studio, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have a Fragment on top of which I am showing a [popup] DialogFragment. The problem is that I cannot get the RelativeLayout which I'm inflating to fill the DialogFragment. Actually, it's *always* filling it horizontally; *never* vertically.

The [popup] DialogFragment (RelativeLayout) has `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `"match_parent"`.

The following screenshots show separate examples. In each case, the white rectangle is the (correctly sized) DialogFragment. The inflated XML is the red and yellow portion (with the TextView). This red and yellow is coming from a background drawable.

[image]
[image]

Notice that the inflated RelativeLayout *always* takes up the entire width and *never* the entire height. Note that I moved the embedded TextView (for the last two screenshots) to illustrate two points:

(1) It's the position of this TextView that's determining the height of the inflated layout.

(2) Its position has no effect on the width.

Also note:

- The TextView's `layout_alignParentStart` and `layout_alignParentTop` are both `true`
- If I remove the TextView completely, the inflated layout "disappears" (presumably because I now have a "height" of zero).

Screenshots #2 and #5 (second column) are the same - except for the position of the TextView.

The same is true of #3 and #6 (third column).

*(The TextView is mostly vertical in the red area in screenshot #6. It's very difficult to see here, but that's where it is - right of the yellow, with its bottom aligned to the bottom of the yellow area.)*

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Code chunks:

**ZzzDialog.kt** (source of the [popup] DialogFragment):

```
package com.zazzem.two.dialogs

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class ZzzDialog : DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var popup: View

    private var popupLft: Int = 0
    private var popupTop: Int = 0
    private var popupWid: Int = 0
    private var popupHgt: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        popup = inflater.inflate(com.zazzem.two.R.layout.dialog_zzz, null)

        return activity!!.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setView(popup)
            builder.create()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val win = dialog!!.window!!
        win.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT) //top left first, so x & y below will be relative to there
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val win = dialog!!.window ?: return
        val params = win.attributes
        params.x = popupLft
        params.y = popupTop
        params.width = popupWid
        params.height = popupHgt
        win.attributes = params
    }

    fun setPosAndSize(lft: Int, top: Int, wid: Int, hgt: Int) {
        popupLft = lft
        popupTop = top
        popupWid = wid
        popupHgt = hgt
    }
}
```

**the [TEMP] ClickListener** (where the call to "setup" and show the [popup] is made from):

```
        btnDevTemp.setOnClickListener {
            fun doOne(l: Int, t: Int, w: Int, h: Int) {
                dialog_specs.text = "Lft:$l Top:$t Wid:$w Hgt:$h"
                val dlg = ZzzDialog()
                dlg.setPosAndSize(l, t, w, h)
                dlg.show(activity!!.supportFragmentManager, "ZzzDialog")
            }
            doOne(100,200,800,800) //pic #1
            //doOne(10,10,1200,1900) //pic #2 and #5
            //doOne(500,500,800,1200) //pic #3 and #6
            //doOne(300,300,450, 900) //pic #4
        }
```

**XML for [popup] DialogFragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkgr_zzz"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Pink"
        android:text="TextView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML for the above's `background`**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        >
        <!-- yellow -->
        <solid android:color="#FFFF00" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="20dp"
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:top="20dp"
            />
        <!-- red -->
        <stroke
            android:width="25dp"
            android:color="#FF0000"
            />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Get height of the dialog fragment programatically like this :

```
int height  = getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
```

Then, get a reference of that parent RelativeLayout and set it's height programatically as well.

```
relativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```

Comment: I just added `popup.layoutParams.height = popupHgt` as the last line in `ZzzDialog.onResume`. The popup (RelativeLayout) _is_ bigger. _Too big._ I am guessing it's related to stroke and/or padding in the background drawable. I'm sure I could finagle some workaround **_if I have to_**. However, this is the first time I'm dealing with "popups" and really want to know how to inflate a (any) layout into the popup. This will serve me well as I add more and more of these "dialogs" to my apps.

Comment: <my code is all in Kotlin> I also tried (again, last in onResume): `val decorHgt = dialog!!.window!!.decorView.height` 
        `popup.layoutParams.height = decorHgt` with that all I have is a white box (not seeing any of the drawable, nor its TextView)